# TextFormField label text size change on focus

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to change text font size when focus?

This method not working

```
TextFormField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'test',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: myFocusNode.hasFocus ? 20 : 14
        )
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a small code sample from my project. Change your TextFormField as follows:

```
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: _focusNode.hasFocus ? 30.0: 33.0,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Search",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
     fontSize:
     _focusNode.hasFocus? 30.0: 33.0,
    ),
  autofocus: false,
),
```

Change your **decoration** code. Note this in the sample code

```
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: _focusNode.hasFocus
? 30.0: 33.0,
```

and here:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: "Search",
hintStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
_focusNode.hasFocus? 30.0: 33.0,
),
```

[My Repo Source](https://github.com/NaagAlgates/GroupOnUiChallenge)